# How to access each single value from associative array having space in key

Tags: php, arrays, key, whitespace

I want to access each value in my json array and store this data in a MySQL database using php:

```
{
    "api": {
        "results": 16,
        "statistics": {
            "Shots on Goal": {
                "home": "5",
                "away": "2"
            },
            "Shots off Goal": {
                "home": "7",
                "away": "4"
            },
            .....
            "Passes %": {
                "home": "91%",
                "away": "88%"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i am using php and i tried different solutions the json_decode($result, true) and the {'Shots on Goal'} but this show errors and sometine it give all values i want to individually access all values

brother first of all thanks alot and this is my complete array please suggest me what i do.{
    "api": {
        "results": 16,
        "statistics": {
            "Shots on Goal": {
                "home": "5",
                "away": "2"
            },
            "Shots off Goal": {
                "home": "7",
                "away": "4"
            },
            "Total Shots": {
                "home": "17",
                "away": "8"
            },
            "Blocked Shots": {
                "home": "5",
                "away": "2"
            },
            "Shots insidebox": {
                "home": "12",
                "away": "5"
            },
            "Shots outsidebox": {
                "home": "5",
                "away": "3"
            },
            "Fouls": {
                "home": "15",
                "away": "14"
            },
            "Corner Kicks": {
                "home": "9",
                "away": "1"
            },
            "Offsides": {
                "home": "2",
                "away": "2"
            },
            "Ball Possession": {
                "home": "61%",
                "away": "39%"
            },
            "Yellow Cards": {
                "home": "2",
                "away": "3"
            },
            "Red Cards": {
                "home": "",
                "away": ""
            },
            "Goalkeeper Saves": {
                "home": "1",
                "away": "4"
            },
            "Total passes": {
                "home": "633",
                "away": "414"
            },
            "Passes accurate": {
                "home": "575",
                "away": "365"
            },
            "Passes %": {
                "home": "91%",
                "away": "88%"
            }
        }
    }
}
this is my complete array

Comment: and with what language? please provide at least some information on what you have tried so far and in which language you want to accomplish this.

Comment: in php, i tried json_decode($result, true) and in foreach loop i access the value but it give me all the value and when i try to access single value it does not work

Comment: Please post the code that you have used.

Comment: $statistics_data= json_decode($result, true);
                     
                    if(!empty($statistics_data)) //file have some data
                    {
                            foreach($statistics_data['api']['statistics']['Shots on Goal'] as  $fix_state)
                            { 
                                $test = $fix_state['home'];
                                print_r($test);}}

Comment: when i try to access value of 'home' in 'Shots on Goal' it give me both the home and away value

Comment: please edit your own post to include this code. no one wants to read that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

It will make insert query, It will work, I cheched.

```
$va = '{
    "api": {
        "results": 16,
        "statistics": {
            "Shots on Goal": {
                "home": "5",
                "away": "2"
            },
            "Shots off Goal": {
                "home": "7",
                "away": "4"
            },
            "Passes %": {
                "home": "91%",
                "away": "88%"
            }
        }
    }
}';
$data = json_decode($va);
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3)";
$insert_value='';
foreach($data->api->statistics as $value){
    $insert_value.="('".$value->home."', '".$value->away."', '".$data->api->results."'),";
}

$final_insert_query =  rtrim($insert_value, ',');
$sqlinsert.='VALUES'.$final_insert_query;
echo $sqlinsert;
```

INSERT INTO fixture_statistics(`id`, `fixture_id`, `Shots_on_Goal_home`, `Shots_on_Goal_away`, `Shots_of_Goal_home`, `Shots_of_Goal_away`, `Total_Shots_home`, `Total_Shots_away`, `Blocked_Shots_home`, `Blocked_Shots_away`, `Shots_insidebox_home`, `Shots_insidebox_away`, `Shots_outsidebox_home`, `Shots_outsidebox_away`, `Fouls_home`, `Fouls_away`, `Corner_Kicks_home`, `Corner_Kicks_away`, `Offsides_home`, `Offsides_away`, `Ball_Possession_home`, `Ball_Possession_away`, `Yellow_Cards_home`, `Yellow_Cards_away`, `Red_Cards_home`, `Red_Cards_away`, `Goalkeeper_Saves_home`, `Goalkeeper_Saves_away`, `Total_passes_home`, `Total_passes_away`, `Passes_accurate_home`, `Passes _accurate_away`, `Passes_percentage_home`, `Passes_percentage_away`, `create_date`)VALUES(0',3', '5','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',6', '3','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',13', '9','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',4', '1','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',9', '5','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',4', '4','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',20', '19','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',6', '4','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',5', '1','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',56%', '44%','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',0', '1','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',0', '0','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',3', '3','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',413', '316','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',265', '176','2019-11-11 11:13:48'),(0',64%', '56%','2019-11-11 11:13:48'

Comment: It will make this query                                                                                                             INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3)VALUES('5', '2', '16'),('7', '4', '16'),('91%', '88%', '16')

Comment: first of all thanks alot brother i update my question and need your suggestion

Comment: You want to insert index also? then let me know.

Comment: brother look at my table

Comment: Where is your table?

Comment: INSERT INTO fixture_statistics(  Shots_on_Goal_home, Shots_on_Goal_away, Shots_of_Goal_home, Shots_of_Goal_away, Total_Shots_home, Total_Shots_away, Blocked_Shots_home, Blocked_Shots_away, Shots_insidebox_home, Shots_insidebox_away, Shots_outsidebox_home, Shots_outsidebox_away, Fouls_home, Fouls_away, Corner_Kicks_home, Corner_Kicks_away, Offsides_home, Offsides_away, Ball_Possession_home, Ball_Possession_away, Yellow_Cards_home, Yellow_Cards_away, Red_Cards_home, Red_Cards_away, Goalkeeper_Saves_home, Goalkeeper_Saves_away, Total_passes_away,   Passes_percentage_away)

Comment: Got it , Let me see this

Comment: i delete some column because here indicate the maximum characters options

Comment: Please Check your answer,

Comment: add me skp-epe , i will fix your problem. My username is Raokaleemullah786

Answer (score 0):

```
$va = '{ "api": { "results": 16, "statistics": { 
"Shots on Goal": 
{ "home": "5", "away": "2" },

 "Shots off Goal":
 { "home": "7", "away": "4" }, 
"Total Shots": { "home": "17", "away": "8" },
 "Blocked Shots": { "home": "5", "away": "2" },
 "Shots insidebox": { "home": "12", "away": "5" }, 
"Shots outsidebox": { "home": "5", "away": "3" }, "Fouls": { "home": "15", "away": "14" }, "Corner Kicks": { "home": "9", "away": "1" },
 "Offsides": { "home": "2", "away": "2" }, "Ball Possession": { "home": "61%", "away": "39%" }, 
"Yellow Cards": { "home": "2", "away": "3" }, "Red Cards": { "home": "", "away": "" }, 
"Goalkeeper Saves": { "home": "1", "away": "4" }, "Total passes": { "home": "633", "away": "414" }, 
"Passes accurate": { "home": "575", "away": "365" }, "Passes %": { "home": "91%", "away": "88%" } } } } ';
$data = json_decode($va);
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO fixture_statistics (Shots_on_Goal_home, 
Shots_on_Goal_away, Shots_of_Goal_home, Shots_of_Goal_away, Total_Shots_home, Total_Shots_away, Blocked_Shots_home, Blocked_Shots_away, Shots_insidebox_home, Shots_insidebox_away, Shots_outsidebox_home, Shots_outsidebox_away, Fouls_home, Fouls_away, Corner_Kicks_home, Corner_Kicks_away, Offsides_home, Offsides_away, Ball_Possession_home, Ball_Possession_away, Yellow_Cards_home, Yellow_Cards_away, Red_Cards_home, Red_Cards_away, Goalkeeper_Saves_home, Goalkeeper_Saves_away, Total_passes_away, Passes_percentage_away)";
$insert_value='';
foreach($data->api->statistics as $key=> $value){
    if($key == 'Shots on Goal'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
    elseif($key == 'Total Shots'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
    elseif($key == 'Blocked Shots'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
    elseif($key == 'Shots insidebox'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
     elseif($key == 'Shots outsidebox'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
     elseif($key == 'Fouls'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
     elseif($key == 'Corner Kicks'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
       elseif($key == 'Offsides'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
       elseif($key == 'Ball Possession'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
       elseif($key == 'Yellow Cards'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
       elseif($key == 'Red Cards'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }

       elseif($key == 'Goalkeeper Saves'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }
       elseif($key == 'Total passes'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }


       elseif($key == 'Passes accurate'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }

       elseif($key == 'Passes %'){
        $insert_value.="'".$value->home."', '".$value->away."',";
    }

}

$final_insert_query =  rtrim($insert_value, ',');
$sqlinsert.='VALUES('.$final_insert_query.")";
echo $sqlinsert;
```

It will generate this Query for your table.

```
INSERT INTO fixture_statistics (Shots_on_Goal_home, 
Shots_on_Goal_away, Shots_of_Goal_home, Shots_of_Goal_away, Total_Shots_home, Total_Shots_away, Blocked_Shots_home, Blocked_Shots_away, Shots_insidebox_home, Shots_insidebox_away, Shots_outsidebox_home, Shots_outsidebox_away, Fouls_home, Fouls_away, Corner_Kicks_home, Corner_Kicks_away, Offsides_home, Offsides_away, Ball_Possession_home, Ball_Possession_away, Yellow_Cards_home, Yellow_Cards_away, Red_Cards_home, Red_Cards_away, Goalkeeper_Saves_home, Goalkeeper_Saves_away, Total_passes_away, Passes_percentage_away)VALUES('5', '2','17', '8','5', '2','12', '5','5', '3','15', '14','9', '1','2', '2','61%', '39%','2', '3','', '','1', '4','633', '414','575', '365','91%', '88%')
```

Comment: brother you send static data to database but here i have data comming from api and data will be change everytime

Comment: I did not get it , What do you want to say?